# What is “uplink redundancy” in ESXi free web client?

Tags: ubuntu, virtualization, vmware-esxi, virtualhost, virtual-machines

Attempting to bride network between ESXi and my newly created Ubuntu vm. In Network settings in ESXi host client , it reads “This virtual switch has no uplink redundancy.”  What is uplink redundancy? Do I need this to bridge the vms to host (trying to connect and get internet access...been days). Thank you very much, in advance

Answer (score 2):

No you do not need this. If you wanted, though, you can use two uplinks from the ESXi server to your switchgear. With this, if one fails, ESXi can failover all the VM traffic to the good link.

Typically each VM host will be uplinked to at least two discrete switches (each of which has redundant uplinks to the core), protecting against both cable failure as well as switch failure.

Comment: very, very informative for me. thank you. I'm very new to esxi.